# URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out> when I try to load the GTZAN dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, torchaudio

I am trying to load the GTZAN dataset from PyTorch using torchaudio.datasets.GTZAN

`gtzan_dataset = torchaudio.datasets.GTZAN(root='./data', download=True) waveform, sample_rate, label = gtzan_dataset[0]`

This is the error I am getting

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip0j2.png)